# Groovy Sql.call how to call SP with default value

Tags: sql, groovy

```
private static String XXX = "{call SP_XXX(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}"
sql.call (XXX, [Sql.NUMERIC, Sql.NUMERIC, 'somevalue',default,default,default,'somevalue'])
```

I want to set the last IN parameter to 'somevalue' without setting other unnecessary parameters. In another word keep them as default values in the SP.

Is there a way to do that in groovy?

Note: default is not valid expression here. And I can set them to null. But, the SP will use null instead of default value in execusion.

Comment: It is going to depend a lot on the type of database.

Comment: It's oracle 11g database. But, I don't think it's relate to database. I think it's still on groovy side.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is more a JDBC question than a groovy one.

Anyways, you could probably do this:

```java
private static String XXX = "{call SP_XXX(?,?,?,default,default,default,?)"
sql.call (XXX, [Sql.NUMERIC, Sql.NUMERIC, 'somevalue', 'somevalue'])
```

Since this is pretty obvious, I'm guessing you don't know which parameters you will want to use when you instantiate your "XXX" String, in which case you'll have to build your String programmatically just before calling `sql.call()`.

Something like that, perhaps (though untested):

```java
// params is a HashMap with the param number as key
def callXXX = { params ->
    def str = 'call SP_XXX('
    def paramsPlaceholders = []
    1.upto(7) { i ->
        if (params[i]) {
            paramsPlaceholders << '?'
        } else {
            paramsPlaceholders << 'default'
        }
    }
    str += paramsPlaceHolders.join(',')
    str += ')'
    return sql.call(str, params.values())
}
```

You could even build on this to make a generic solution that could be added to the sql metaClass, and live happily ever after.